# Flutter Exception Error Handling Google Apps Script generated json

Tags: json, flutter, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Developing my first Flutter mobile app, a code snippet to fetch a json from:

```
'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts'
```

...successfully responds, decodes, parses, etc. Then when i test with doc uploaded to git as:

```
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rays-github/theirmenu/master/db.json'
```

...this also works. But when I try to use my own data (Google Web Apps Script publishing a Google Sheets spreadsheet as json):

```
'https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=_DZABYr6b6k274bCyLNtzSBd1jtYF_WpuFDYAtNQT-uE6uj0teMefPEiNDxNisIH0ew63RSj757Xh5smCcvouuLLk_VcYyB8m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnPKmEGJr49ifP_3P8Fcnrtzcwn0zyFgFMfS_we8kf_vIvupeaUN7ec2K60MRzRqUBQ&lib=MNDmyszRDOPMr7WJ3Tg4jKCcl7uh4ZtSK'
```

...I get errors:

```
Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
^
)
```

Here is my Flutter snippet:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:theirmenu001pt00/tm_menuitem_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class HttpService {
  // final String postsUrl = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts";
  // final String postsUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rays-github/theirmenu/master/db.json";
  final String postsUrl = "https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=7zmRRkd__iPae6VZ9oq5TTNjfEm3QQV9EYBvQN-awvPS4-HNw2C4wbUSC8ud0J9rfFuxXvwhWPMjiJj5GUVQvGHDvinAYraCm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnPKmEGJr49ifP_3P8Fcnrtzcwn0zyFgFMfS_we8kf_vIvupeaUN7ec2K60MRzRqUBQ&lib=MNDmyszRDOPMr7WJ3Tg4jKCcl7uh4ZtSK";

  Future<List<Post>> getMenuItems() async {
    Response res = await get(postsUrl);

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);

      List<Post> posts =
          body.map((dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item)).toList();

      return posts;
    } else {
      throw "Can't get posts.";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my Google Web App Script:

```
function doGet(e){

 // Sheet url
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jsBS-RBNRxYU66WFkJHvrzHLGmNqxBzzQfaHJO6i6UY/edit#gid=446843772");

// Sheet Name
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Users");
  
 return getUsers(sheet); 
  
}


function getUsers(sheet){
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];

// collecting data from 2nd Row , 1st column to last row and last column
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0, l= rows.length; i<l ; i++){
    var dataRow = rows[i];
    var record = {};
    record['userId'] = dataRow[0];
    record['id'] = dataRow[1];
    record['title'] = dataRow[2];
    record['body'] = dataRow[3];
    
    dataArray.push(record);
    
  }  
  
  jo = dataArray;
  
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  
}
```

SCREENSHOT - MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO CODE RUN:
[image: SCREENSHOT - MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO CODE RUN]

SCREENSHOT - UNAUTHENTICATED REQUEST VIA BROWSER:
[image: SCREENSHOT - UNAUTHENTICATED REQUEST VIA BROWSER]
Please, advise. Any help is greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Almost certainly you are being presented with a login screen rather than JSON, because you are not making authenticated requests to your Apps Script endpoint. You don't mention where in your Flutter code the error is thrown, but my guess is it occurs at the `jsonDecode` statement. Try instead logging the output and you will see the rest of the page.

Comment: I think that the URL you are using like `https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=###&lib=###` is the redirected URL for the Web Apps of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. But when you request to such URL without the redirect, the status of 302 is returned. In this case, it is required to use the redirect for requesting to `https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=###&lib=###`.

Comment: So at first, can you test using a simple curl command for confirming whether the value you expect is returned? In this case, it's `curl -L "https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=###&lib=###"`. When the correct value can be retrieved, how about modifying your script for redirecting and testing it again?

Comment: ah, yes.. it seems both you (@tehhowch, @Tanaike) have determined valid reasons for my error. as a novice, i'm still trying to wrap my head around them and possible solutions. but the reason navigating to that url in my browser works is because i'm logged in as the web apps script's creator. and so when my flutter app runs (as anon? user i'm guessing) an Access Request page is returned.

Comment: so, @tehhowch, is it possible to have my flutter app authenticate before requesting? ...is that a safe solution.. to have a publicly available mobile app that makes authenticated requests to my google web apps script?? if not, is there an appropriate and/or safe way for my publicly available flutter app to run my google web apps script?

Comment: @Tanaike, should i mod my google web apps script to make authenticated requests... is it safe? ..is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand at about the relationship between my comment and `should i mod my google web apps script to make authenticated requests... is it safe? ..is there a more appropriate way?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike, Ok. Although, after thinking about this and researching more, I think unauthorized access to the Google Apps Script is the issue. So modifying the Google Apps Script would not work. I need to figure out how to make the Flutter app authenticate itself so that it can access/run the Google Apps Script.

Comment: Looks like you didn't authenticate when making your request. To achieve this, you will need to get OAuth2 credentials with [this package](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth), and then use these credentials in your request. The exact workflow will depend on what type of application this is an whether you want to skip `user consent` step. An easier option would be making your web app publicly accessible, but I guess that's not desired.

Comment: @Iamblichus is there a reason why i wouldnt want to make my web app publicly accessible? ..security concerns? ..if so, what could happen?

Comment: I just thought you wanted to avoid that since you didn't do it before, but there shouldn't be a problem. The only thing is anyone with the URL could access the content returned by the web app (that is, data from your spreadsheet). If that's not a problem for you, it would be the easiest way to solve this. What do you think?

Comment: Also, to make this more secure, you could for example pass a certain query parameter to your request with flutter, and at the beginning of the `doGet` function, check that this parameter matches. If not, don't provide the data. This way, only requests coming from the Flutter app would get the spreadsheet data.

Comment: @Iamblichus, oh, yes, i like the query parameter idea. can you recommend a resource with more info (howto, etc.)? thanks!

Comment: I see you're not accessing the web app URL directly, but using a URL that redirects to it. This might cause a problem with the workaround I suggested. Would you consider using [this URL](https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/s/AKfycbyYFBPEJTIO1fDMQ1m1t9rVt1u4ntBQT2f5ezXImdd5/dev) directly?